# Weight Painting in 2.80 in edit mode

Tags: edit-mode, weight-painting

I jumped from 2.7 to to 2.80 and I am having trouble with the new weight painting workflow. What I would like to do, is to weightpaint specific vertices and faces in edit mode while seing the color code of the weight painting. But all I can do is either use the brush in weightpaint mode freehand style, or apply the weight 'blindly' in edit mode and then check the colors in weight mode. Am I missing something? This was way faster for me in 2.7. I am looking for suggestions of a better workflow for 2.80.
Thanks for being nice.

In the screenshot below I would like to select the individual faces. That's only possible in edit-mode, right? But in edit-mode there is no visible color coding for the weight painting, right?

[image]

Comment: If my question is too unspesific please comment so I know how to better ask it or delete it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to my question is simple. After some soulsearching in blender 2.8 I found the checkbox in a new place. The 'Weight Table' is also there like in 2.7. So all is well and good in blenderland. Here a gif for another adventurer to not have to search as I had to.
[image]